# MSBuild can't build an MSI. Are there alternatives for a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, deployment, windows-services

I use the Setup project (.msi) in Visual Studio.

Install steps:

1. Building the setup in Visual Studio.
2. Copy setup to the server.
3. Run the setup.
4. Start the Windows Service in services.msc

Update steps:

1. Building the setup in Visual Studio.
2. Copy setup to the server.
3. Stop the Windows service in services.msc
4. Uninstall Windows service.
5. Run the setup.
6. Start the Windows service in services.msc

My build server only uses msbuild to build and can't build Setup project (.msi).

Must I install Visual Studio on my build server, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: The steps you mentioned looks fine. Is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using installutil.exe is much easier and faster... you can use `installutil /u myservice.exe` to stop and uninstall the service on the server, delete old files, copy new files over and use `installutil myservice.exe` to re-install your service...

Answer (score 1):

For this I use Phil Wilsons ReadSvcXml.exe tool which when run as a post build event on the setup project updates the installer msi file with specific info relivant to the service (ie including adding dependancies, to stop the service on uninstall, to register it etc).  This is the simplest and most reliable way to start the service automatically on completion of the install.

Eg post build event for setup project is:
..\ReadSvcXml.exe MyApplication.msi ..\ServiceSetup.xml

Where ServiceSetup.xml looks like:

```xml
<ServiceData>
  <FileName>MyServiceHost.exe</FileName>
  <ServiceInstall>
    <Id>ServiceInstallColumn</Id>
    <Name>GatewayServer</Name>
    <DisplayName>Company MyServer</DisplayName>
    <ServiceType>ownprocess </ServiceType> <!-- or shareprocess-->
    <Interactive>no</Interactive>
    <Start>auto</Start> <!--auto demand or disabled-->
    <ErrorControl>
    <!--ignore normal critical -->
    normal
    </ErrorControl>
    <Dependencies>MSSQLSERVER</Dependencies>
    <Description>MyServer for blar blar blar</Description>
  </ServiceInstall>
  <ServiceControl>
    <Name>MyServerName</Name>
    <Id>MyServerId</Id>
    <!-- install, uninstall or both-->
    <Start>install</Start>
    <Stop>both</Stop>
    <Remove>uninstall</Remove>  
    <Wait>no</Wait> <!-- no yes -->
  </ServiceControl>
</ServiceData>
```

SvcInstall can be downloaded here:
[download svcinstall bin and source](http://www.installsite.org/files/iswi/SvcInstall.zip)